# How do you know if actionevent was generated by button or textfield at runtime?

Tags: java, swing

How do you know if actionevent was generated by button or textfield at runtime?

Answer (score 3):

Use [getSource()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29) to check which component that fired the event.

```
final JButton b = new JButton("Button");
final JTextField f = new JTextField("TextField");

ActionListener l = new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == b) {
            /* button fired the event */
        }

        if (e.getSource() == f) {
            /* text field fired the event */
        }
    }
};

b.addActionListener(l);
f.addActionListener(l);
```

Answer (score 1):

Could also use actionCommands for differentiating between the two.

```
JButton button = new JButton("Button");
JTextField field = new JTextField("TextField");

ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String command = event.getActionCommand();
        if (command.equals("myButton") {
            //Button stuff
        }

        if (command.equals("myField") {
            //Field stuff
        }
    }
};

button.addActionListener(listener);
button.setActionCommand("myButton");

field.addActionListener(listener);
field.setActionCommand("myField");
```